# What is the meaning of "night for all living beings and day for all living beings"?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

[Source: BG 2.69](http://srimadbhagavadgita.net/bhagavad-gita-chapter-2-verse-69):

> yå niçå sarva-bhütånåµ tasyåµ jågarti saµyamî

> yasyåµ jågrati bhütåni så niçå paçyato mune˙

TRANSLATION:

> That which is day for the self-controlled sage is night for all living
> beings, and that which is day for all living beings is night for the
> introspective sage.

I'm   not getting the meaning  of this  verse.

I'm thinking  is that  to be  a yogi  you must  be  night worker and sleep  on   day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swami Mukundanand explained it in this way.

> Let us try and understand the true meaning of Shree Krishna’s words. Those who are in mundane consciousness look to material enjoyment as the real purpose of life. They consider the opportunity for worldly pleasures as the success of life, or “day,” and deprivation from sense pleasures as darkness, or “night.” On the other hand, those who have become wise with divine knowledge, see sense enjoyment as harmful for the soul, and hence view it as “night.” They consider refraining from the objects of the senses as elevating to the soul, and hence look on it as “day.” Using those connotations of the words, Shree Krishna states that what is night for the sage is day for the worldly-minded people, and vice versa.

## I'm thinking is that to be a yogi you must be night worker and sleep on day.

No. This assumption is completely wrong. Swami ji made it clear.

> There was once a Khade Shree Baba (the standing ascetic), whose disciples claimed he was a very big sage. He had not slept in thirty-five years. He would stand in his room, resting on a hanging rope under his armpits. He used the rope to help him remain in the standing position. On being asked what his motivation was for this destructive kind of austerity, he would quote this verse of the Bhagavad Gita: “What all beings see as night, the enlightened sage sees as day.” So to practice it, he had given up sleeping at night. What a misunderstanding of the verse! From all that standing, his feet and lower legs were swollen, and so he could practically do nothing except stand.

Source:- https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2/verse/69

Srila Prabhupada also gave a similar explanation.

> There are two classes of intelligent men. The one is intelligent in material activities for sense gratification, and the other is introspective and awake to the cultivation of self-realization. Activities of the introspective sage, or thoughtful man, are night for persons materially absorbed. **Materialistic persons remain asleep in such a night due to their ignorance of self-realization.** The introspective sage remains alert in the "night" of the materialistic men. The sage feels transcendental pleasure in the gradual advancement of spiritual culture, whereas the man in materialistic activities, being asleep to self-realization, dreams of varieties of sense pleasure, feeling sometimes happy and sometimes distressed in his sleeping condition. The introspective man is always indifferent to materialistic happiness and distress. He goes on with his self-realization activities undisturbed by material reaction.

> https://asitis.com/2/69.html

Answer (score 3):

It means that the values held dear by Yogis are opposite to the values held dear by ordinary people.

> To people who are sense-bound things earthly are all real and they are
> immersed in them; they are wakeful to the mundane. To the
> Brahma-jnani, on the other hand, who has conquered the senses and who
> has awakened to divine consciousness, the spectacle is different. His
> intuition, his concepts, his percepts are all filled in with Divinity.
> Whatever is, is Brahman to him. He cognizes existence as Brahman and
> not as the mundane. According to the attainment, beings are attuned to
> different planes of existence. The enlightened one is in the finale of
> it.

**The Bhagavada Gita 2.69 commentary by Swami Chidbhavananda**